# PHP: Append to thrown exception message

Tags: php, exception

Take the following function as an example of what I want to do:

```
public function save() {
    $this->connect('wb');
    try {
        if(!$this->lock())
            throw new Exception("Unable to acquire configuration locks");
        if (!$backup = $this->backup())
            throw new Exception("Failed to create configuration backup");
        try {
            if(!fwrite($this->_pointer, $this->dump("string")));
                throw new Exception("Error occured while writing to configuration");
            $this->unlock();
            $this->disconnect();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if(rename ($backup, $this->_file))
                $e .= PHP_EOL."Successfully restored configuration from backup";
            else
                $e .= PHP_EOL."Failed to restore configuration from backup";
            $this->unlock();
            $this->disconnect();
            throw $e;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo PHP_EOL, $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I have nested `try()` and `catch()` statements. An exception is thrown from the inner-most and is caught, I then perform some functions and throw another exception. Notice where I write `$e .=`, I understand this is the incorrect syntax. What I want to do is append the string to the exception's `$e->getMessage()`.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create you own exception class and create method for appending string to the message.

```
<?php
class SuperException extends Exception
{
    public function AppendToMessage($msg)
    {
        // $this->message is inherited from Exception class,
        // where it is protected field (member) of the class
        $this->message .= $msg;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the review ManseUK.
@Milad Naseri, after all the code should be clean as much, as possible and easy to find and extend for new features and functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Most object-oriented language frameworks that support exception handling realize the need for this subject. You need to understand that *Exceptions* are not *logs* of what happened. Rather, they are there to pinpoint exactly where the error occurred.

So, not only that syntax is incorrect, the whole idea violates a dozen OOD principles. You should introduce a logger class, that collects information about the errors as you go, and use the exceptions to pinpoint the *events* that need to be recorded.

```
class ErrorLogger {

    private $log;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->log = array();
    }

    public function log(Exception $e) {
        array_push($this->log, $e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

and further in your code:

```
$logger = new ErrorLogger();
try {
    :
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $logger->log($e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I intend to display only the message to users and detailed information to higher level users, however I have to disagree. The main purpose of an exception to me is to perform error specific logic. I don't believe it is violating OOD principles. If one of my users saw a verbose error they would be frightened and leave, if they saw "a database error occured" then they are less likely to be as frightened.

Comment: My logger here performs only a sample logic. Your own implementation could use an interface with two implementations: one for higher level users and one for end users.

Comment: Don't get me wrong I am not knocking your logger. I think it's a good idea. I'm going to display one simple exception message and use my own exception class to log to an error file on the server.

Comment: I didn't think that you did ;) I was just being stubborn and stuck to my own idea.
But I understand where you're coming from, too. And that's one way to use exceptions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a separate variable to keep the messages ?

```
public function save() {
    $this->connect('wb');
    $exceptionMessage = "";
    try {
        if(!$this->lock())
            throw new Exception("Unable to acquire configuration locks");
        if (!$backup = $this->backup())
            throw new Exception("Failed to create configuration backup");
        try {
            if(!fwrite($this->_pointer, $this->dump("string")));
                throw new Exception("Error occured while writing to configuration");
            $this->unlock();
            $this->disconnect();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if(rename ($backup, $this->_file))
                $exceptionMessage .= PHP_EOL."Successfully restored configuration from backup";
            else
                $exceptionMessage .= PHP_EOL."Failed to restore configuration from backup";
            $this->unlock();
            $this->disconnect();
            throw $e;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo PHP_EOL. $exceptionMessage . PHP_EOL . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be worth a new class. Just catch your exception and throw a new one appending to the old message.

```
try { 
    /* Something which might fail */
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $msg = "My custom message " . $e->getMessage();
    throw(new \Exception($msg));
}
```